# How to increase the shards in an existing elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch

I have to increase the shards in an existing index with out deleting the index

I found that we have to recreate the index then only we will be able to increase the no of shards in an index. Is their any best approach to increase the no of shards in an existing index without deleting the existing index.

Thanks,
Kiran

Comment: No, You can't do that. Shards are **one time setting** (you set them when creating index). You would have to create a new index and then reindex the data.

Comment: Or use the re-index API in the same cluster ;-). But, yeah the main point is you can't change the number of primary shards

Comment: Thanks @ChintanShah25 and Andrei Stefan